# How to change keys of associative array and modify the array?

Tags: javascript

I have an associative array with some data as shown in below.

```
const x = {
  fields = {
      1: {},
      2:{},
      3:{},
      5:{}
      6:{}
  }   
}
```

How I can change the positions for objects inside the `fields`.
**for example:** If i give postion as 6 to 3 then the object 6 should goto 3 and 3 will goto 4 accordingly. Please help.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov fields is an object, so i don't think splice will help here

Comment: What you have is an object of objects of objects, there's no array here.

Comment: I don't want to remove any object I just wanted to change the positions and maintain proper filed object keys

Comment: The pseudo-code you have posted doesn't seem to be valid javascript notation. Furthermore, sorting object properties doesn't make much sense. If you need *associative* data structure with properties arranged in certain order, have a look at [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
const x = {
    fields: {
        1: {},
        2: {},
        3: {},
        5: {},
        6: {}
    }
};


const move = (object, from, to) => {
    let a = new Map();
    const entries = Object.entries(object);
    entries.map(([k, v]) => {
        if (k < to && k != from) {
            a.set(k, v);
        }

    });
    a.set(from, object[from]);
    entries.map(([k, v]) => {
        if (k != from) {
            a.set(k, v);
        }

    });
    return a;
}
x.fields = move(x.fields, 6, 3);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer. After you replace 6 with 3 the position of 6 will change to 3 and 3 will become 4 like all keys will update.